# Accessing WebSphere Application Server 8 installation folder in RAD (Rational Application Developer)

Tags: websphere-8, ibm-rad

I'm using ant build to build an ejb client and I need a WAS installation folder path included in a `build.properties` file for creating ejb stubs.

An entry in a property file looks something like this:

```
server.dir = C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
```

This entry includes static value for `server.dir` property but I'm looking for more flexible solution (e.g. getting path from some system variable or something like that).

Also I would like to get the right value of the variable on another computer even if the installation directory is different. Is that even possible to achieve?

Thanks for all ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following your question. You can see the installation path in Window > Preferences > Servers > Runtime Environments.

Variables are one way to standardize that, but there is another one using Templates (if you plan to include this path in your code like in a content assist way). For instance, in Java preferences (Window > Preferences > Java) go to Editor > Templates and add a new one. This approach also allows you to export the template and share it with your peers ti be imported in their environments

What do you mean by "I would like to use that information in my application"? Do you mean programatically to get the install location of the WAS you are running from your JavaEE application?

Comment: Updated my question, wrote the original one wrong. My mistake. 

So I'm looking for a way to somehow get WAS installation path in a properties file (if it's even possible).